# Manga where the female lead enters a novel world

Tags: story-identification, manga, reincarnation

The female lead  come to novel world but as a novel; the female main character's friend and the novel female character brother become her love interest and female character  also somehow became a rival of novel male characters

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

Comment: Hmm... I somewhat suspect that this covers a lot of "transmigrated into novel" plots. Did the female lead die to get in there? Is it set in China? Europe? Generic fantasy world? Medieval setting? Prehistoric? Contemporary? Was there magic? Monsters? Chi cultivation? Awareness of system variables and story flags?

Comment: Does the main character have any kind of special power? Do you remember if the sister of the male lead has three or four suitors?